# IE click sound and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Using jQuery, is there a way to disable the click sound in IE that happens when you post?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The IE click sound is a feature of the browser that you can't control from JavaScript. The only way to disable it is in System Sounds in the Control Panel.

Comment: I hate to see this get most votes if My solution solves the problem. But thats life i guess. ;) I can see that everyone vote on this one because of they know the click is a browser click, and dont know that you can fool the browser.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider yours a very stable solution. I'd call it more of a workaround. Workarounds are not maintainable

Comment: And your solution breaks other expected behavior (back/forward) and in a lot of cases, that's just not acceptable

Comment: It "may" be acceptable and sometimes desirable. But I totally understand your point and mostly agree. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It may very well be possible using this solution: http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/11/30/

But in short, John is right about it being a browser sound not controlled by javascrípt or anyting else than a registry change, wich a website will not manage to do.

I know the above "trick" has worked before, so if nothing has changed it will still work.